# Is running safe for me

Tags: running

I am a beginner jogger/runner on a high protein diet. I am 32 years old and have a BMI of 31. I am 175cm (~5'9") tall, and weigh 96kg (211 pounds). I walked for a couple of weeks and now I can run for 2.2km at a speed of 9km/hr. I get tired at the end of my run (after 17 minutes), and my heart rate is at 180bpm. Might this 2.2km run be bad for my heart?

Comment: How do you monitor the heart rate? Also edit the question after finding out your resting heart rate. 180 seems too high for that speed you run.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience as a personal trainer, I would say that regardless of the 180 being accurate, if you are not feeling dizzy, nauseous, or a headache then you are not overdoing your running. Most of the overweight clients who I have trained, would usually feel dizzy and or nauseous when I pushed too hard.

The fact that you are getting tired after only 17 minutes isn't something to worry about either. It can simply mean that you are still not very conditioned, and/or it can be that you are running at a pace that is simply too fast for a long sustainable jog.

The main thing to focus on is your body's communication. The body has a way of telling you when it isn't happy and you will certainly know when that's the case. So long as you feel fine after your run and nothing more than tired then you are ok.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Being 32 years old your theoretical maximum heart rate should be 188(this is from 220 - age). This means you are close to reaching your maximum heart rate but this is nothing dangerous for your heart unless you got a heart disease which prevents you from reaching a high heart rate.</strike>

If I understand you correctly you are indeed feeling very exhausted at the end of your run and as we can't know how well your heart is we can't definitely say that your working out like that is not dangerous. Should you be really concered or start to feel that something wrong you should see a doctor.

FWIW: Generally speaking it's not dangerous for your heart if your work out really hard if you have a healthy heart.

<strike>To consider is the fact that your heart will be fine but you might feel nauseous reaching this level of physical stress(don't know how to put it better). Nevertheless working out like you are doing will make your assumed healthy heart even stronger.</strike>

Comment: -1. 220-age is one of the worst myths in exercise science, and you have no clue about the actual health of the OP's heart.

Comment: @JohnP So that means that(220-age) it is not even close to being accurate? I actually heard a doctor using it two weeks ago. As for the OPs heart I think the person would've given us the information if there we're any diseases or problems before.

Comment: I'm 46. I regularly hit in the 190's on interval training. 220-age was intended as a "safe" level for cardiac rehab patients, and was originally based on a very small sample (< 10 people). And as far as the OP stating if he has a bad heart, he may not know the state of his heart health, very few people know, many assume. Supporting study from an Exercise Physiology journal: http://www.cyclingfusion.com/pdf/220-Age-Origins-Problems.pdf

Comment: @JohnP thanks, maybe I shouldn't trust doctors so much. Funny thing is the same doctor told me I was very healthy after looking at my VO2 Max, blood levels and stuff like that.